# How to put a for loop such that the alpha range from -0.9 to 0.9?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

```
n <- 1000
m <- 1000


alpha <- 0
ybar <- numeric()
for(i in 1:m){
  y <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=alpha),n)
  ybar[i] <- mean(y)
}
CI <- mean(ybar) + c(1,-1)*qnorm(0.025)*sqrt(1/n)*(1/(1-alpha))
width <- abs(abs(CI[1])-abs(CI[2]));width
```

I want to use a for loop to show the values of `CI` and `width` for different type of alpha range from -0.9 to 0.9. After that, plot a graph of `width` against `alpha`. I'm not sure how to use a for loop here as usually the for loop is always something like `for( i in 1:1000)` instead of a range.

Comment: What is `n`,and `m` here

Comment: ops sorry for that, n=m=1000

Comment: If `m` is 1000, you are over from 1 to 1000, then may need a second loop inside for the 'alpha' values?

Comment: i tried for(alpha in seq(-0.9,0.9,0.1)), but it doesn't works

Comment: I thought your alpha would be `alpha <- seq(-0.9, 0.9, 0.1); and then you loop over the sequence i.e. for(j in seq_along(alpha)) arima.sim(model = list(ar = alpha[j], n)`

Comment: `n <- 1000
m <- 1000

width <- numeric()
alpha <- seq(-0.9,0.9,0.1)
for(j in seq_along(alpha)){
  ybar <- numeric()
  for(i in 1:m){
    y <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=alpha[j]),n)
    ybar[i] <- mean(y)
  }
  CI <- mean(ybar) + c(1,-1)*qnorm(0.025)*sqrt(1/n)*(1/(1-alpha[j]))
  width[j] <- abs(abs(CI[1])-abs(CI[2]));width
}
plot(alpha,width,type="l")` I tried to do what you mentioned, but the plot doesn't seems to be correct seems the denominator for stand err is 1-alpha, so alpha increase the width should increase also, any idea where I did wrong?

Comment: Can you check my corrrected loop because you are assigning to elements that don't exist in 'ybar, 'width'.  I preassigned it to a length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the sequence of vector

```
n <- 1000 
m <- 1000 

alpha <- seq(-0.9,0.9,0.1) 
width <- numeric(length(alpha))
for(j in seq_along(alpha)){
  ybar <- numeric(m) 
   for(i in 1:m){
     y  <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=alpha[j]),n) 
     ybar[i] <- mean(y) 
     } 
    CI <- mean(ybar) + c(1,-1)*qnorm(0.025)*sqrt(1/n)*(1/(1-alpha[j])) 
    width[j] <- abs(abs(CI[1])-abs(CI[2]))
 }

plot(alpha, width, type = "l")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code, however, the plot seems weird for me because the denominator for the standard error in `CI ` is `1-alpha[j]`, so the standard error should get larger when alpha increases, hence the width increases as well, but based on the plot, alpha from -0.5 to 0.5 is not an uptrend, any idea why is it?

Comment: @Elvis Not clear though.  Is it related to the sign `-` `-` = `+`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I know where I did wrong already! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: By the way, did you get the message `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)` when you run the code above?

Comment: @Elvis Yes, I got it.  It is a message baseed on the algoriithm detecting Inf values when it takes the min

Comment: so if I use `seq(-0.9,0.9,0.1)`, the alpha would never be -0.9 and 0.9?

Comment: @Elvis not clear about your comment.  alpha starts at -0.9 and ends at 0.9 based on the seq